# Flutter GO_Router pop named and rebuild Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router, gorouter

My example stack in GoRouter:

Page1 -> Page2 -> Page3 -> Page4

In Page4 is a Button do navigate to Page2 ...

If I try context.goNamed('page2') the Widget Page2 (a form filled with user inputs) is not rebuild (data still in state) ... how can I navigate to page2 with force rebuild the widget (initState etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;

```
context.replace('location');
context.replaceNamed('location');
context.pushReplacement('location');
context.pushReplacementNamed('location');
```

Comment: tried all of them...  :-/

Comment: Flutter normally runs initState only once before the screen is drawn. It is not possible to trigger this again. In your case the page is not destroyed but disabled. If you want to take action when you return to the page, you can re-retrieve your data by looking at the difference between the current status and the new status using 'didUpdateWidget'. You can also do this with 'activate'.